# Post image base64 using Flurl

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, flurl

I'm trying to post simple request using Flurl. But there is an exception, because `takenPicture` string is too large. Is there any way to post large string using Flurl?

> System.UriFormatException: Uri is longer than the maximum 32766 characters.

```
var postData = BaseAdress.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new {
   text = Uri.EscapeDataString(body),
   subject = Uri.EscapeDataString(subject),
   from_email = from,
   recipient_email = to,
   picture = takenPicture //Base64 string
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limitation, while a little arbitrary, is [by design in Microsoft's `Uri.EscapeDataString` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx), which is commonly used by applications and libraries (including Flurl) to encode data for both URL queries and URL-encoded request bodies. Both [Xamarin](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36095) and [RestSharp Portable](https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/restsharp.portable/issues/12) have dealt with this so I'm sure a work-around is possible and I might consider this in Flurl if you want to [create an issue](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/new).

However, keep in mind that URL-encoding binary data like images is very unusual, and there are [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/62600) to avoid it if possible. Of course, if this is a 3rd-party API you're working with, you don't have much of a choice. But if you have control of the server-side code, I would suggest refactoring that to accept `multipart/form-data` instead.